# Springboot 2.7 with Oracle 12.2 and Oracle Label Security Passing individual database user account credentials on a per http request to Connection

Tags: proxy, request, connection

I have Web based Springboot 2.7 application with an Oracle 12.2 database.  As of now it uses AutoConfigure option and sets the datasource up through the Tomcat JNDI using a schema owner user/password.  My requirement is I have to use the connect through user proxy mechanism of the Oracle Database.  In strict JDBC using OCI it might look something like this

Properties p = new Properties();
p.put(OracleOCIConnectionPool.PROXY_USER_NAME,userName);
connectionPool.getProxyConnection(OracleOCIConnectionPool.PROXY_TYPE_USER_NAME,p)

From the database it looks something like this assuming "scott" is the proxy user and "user" is connecting through scott.

connect user[scott]/tiger

I dont necessarily need to use OCI and I believe the Oracle thin driver has the same support for authenticating as a proxy user.

Again the requirement for proxy user connection is Oracle Label Security.  Each Oracle Database User Account has a OLS profile that determines what they can see n the database and therefore what hey can see in the web application.

My question is,  I do not see a way to achieve this in Springboot.  As it stands now the datasource builds properly and works with the JNDI Information in tomcat.  I just need to send additional info with the connection on a per request basis.

Reviewed:
https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/classes/org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl

But the API call for getConnection coming off of the ConnectionProvider does not seem to allow for additional inputs such as user name etc

Reviewed:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/old-docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference//html

This Spring Security guide had some info in Chapter 8 on proxy authentication in Chapter 8 "Custom Datasource Configurations.."  But this is obviously old and unless I missed it the Security Guide for 2.7.2 Chapter 9 did not have this.  This leads me to believe it was removed for a reason unless its there and I missed it.

Reviewed:
Numerous posts on multiple datasources and configuring a data source programmatically and Im not understanding how this fits into my requirement.  As it stands now the datasource builds properly and works with the JNDI Information in tomcat.  I just need to send additional info with the connection on a per request basis.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I need to leverage this within Springboot on a per request basis.. meaning different database user accounts .. on a per request basis.

Multi-tenant as shared schema I don't think will work because shared schema only uses a discriminator.  I need to pass a database user account with the   connection object so it can connect through a proxy user.  

Currently trying to extend the ConnectionProvder in Spring but configure() and connect() methods not getting called during the request.  The Constructor() does get called so the AutoConfiguration is finding it

Answer (score 0):

You can pass connection properties programmatically as shown in this [DataSourceSample.java](https://github.com/oracle-samples/oracle-db-examples/blob/main/java/jdbc/ConnectionSamples/DataSourceSample.java). You can also look at [OracleConnection.html](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html) for the list of connection properties that you can use.